# instance variables and constants in coffeescript classes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to define a class in coffeescript, to use it in my rails project. I'm struggling with the syntax for defining CLASS constants and referring to them, this is what I have so far:

```
class Project

  inputFields :
    title: '#title'

  calculateDataList : [
    @inputFields.title
  ]
```

but the browser complains with:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

I'm not sure what would be the right syntax here. could anyone help me?

thanks,

Comment: If `calculateDataList` would be a function instead of an array it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic syntax for a CoffeeScript class:

```
class Add
  constructor: (number1, number2) ->
    @number1 = number1
    @number2 = number 2

  run: ->
    @number1 + @number2
```

I think something like this will work for your code:

```
class Project
  inputFields: ->
    title: '#title'

  calculateDataList: ->
    [this.inputFields().title]
```

`Project` is a class and `inputFields()` and `calculateDataList()` are methods.  To call the `inputFields()` method in `calculateDataList()`, use the `this` keyword.

Run the code with this command:

```
p = new Project
p.calculateDataList()
```

Comment: Don´t you think OP can find that information everywhere on the internet? How about giving a little explaination how your code works and why OP´s does not?!

Comment: @Amberlamps - I agree with your comment and updated my answer.  At first glance, I was having difficulty understanding the question, but hopefully the updated answer is more useful.

Comment: @dongiulio - `new Project` creates an instance of the class (see the bottom part of my answer).  To make the Project class accessible in your JavaScript console, update the class definition to be `class window.Project`

Answer (score 1):

You must save reference to prototype. Try this one:

```
class Project

  inputFields :
    title: '#title'

  calculateDataList : [
    Project::inputFields.title
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code doesn't compile.

I'm not sure what you want, but **this coffeescript code:**

```
class Project

    inputFields :
        title: '#title'

    calculateDataList : [@inputFields.title]
```

**compiles** to the following Javascript:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var Project;

  Project = (function() {
    function Project() {}

    Project.prototype.inputFields = {
      title: '#title'
    };

    Project.prototype.calculateDataList = [Project.inputFields.title];

    return Project;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

Comment: So it *does* compile?

Comment: Then what problem does your answer solve if OP's code already does compile?